# CSS wrapper how to set default height?

Tags: html, css

I made a website but I want to improve the layout.

I wrapped all the div elements from the website inside `<div class="wrapper">`. I want to keep the height of div wrapper 95% by default. The problem is that if I add text to div element which is below, it will exit outside div. How to keep "div wrapper" at stable height even if other div below is empty? and later when I add text it should extend automatically so I could scroll it in the browser. Look at the picture.

[image]

[image]

```
<style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
        .wrapper {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto; 

        }

        .menu {
          /*  background-color: red;*/
            width: 800px;
            height: 100px; 
            
        }
        .maintext {
            border: dashed 2px black; 
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
```

and here's the HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
    <h1>This is my little menu</h1>
</div>
<div class="maintext">
<h2>You can write here what you want</h2>
<p>Ok I will start now

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quam rem officia dolor dicta. Voluptatum, sunt! Atque animi cupiditate quasi. Modi accusamus consequuntur esse quis suscipit, velit obcaecati cumque reprehenderit perferendis.
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque odio tenetur, rem dolorum nesciunt voluptas quia ex alias corrupti, ullam consequatur distinctio cupiditate voluptate praesentium. Rem perspiciatis totam cumque officia.
nde amet saepe optio obcaecati blanditiis sed sequi nostrum quaerat voluptatibus, est libero culpa nemo! Quaerat, eaque.
</p>
</p>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `overflow: auto` property on your wrapper with fixed height if you need to scroll vertically

```css
 body {
            background-color: black;
        }
        .wrapper {
            background-color: blue;
/*             width: 90%; */
          height:400px; /*+++*/
          overflow: auto; /*+++*/
            margin: 0 auto; 

        }

        .menu {
          /*  background-color: red;*/
            width: 800px;
            height: 100px; 
            
        }
        .maintext {
            border: dashed 2px black; 
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
    <h1>This is my little menu</h1>
</div>
<div class="maintext">
<h2>You can write here what you want</h2>
<p>Ok I will start now

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quam rem officia dolor dicta. Voluptatum, sunt! Atque animi cupiditate quasi. Modi accusamus consequuntur esse quis suscipit, velit obcaecati cumque reprehenderit perferendis.
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque odio tenetur, rem dolorum nesciunt voluptas quia ex alias corrupti, ullam consequatur distinctio cupiditate voluptate praesentium. Rem perspiciatis totam cumque officia.
nde amet saepe optio obcaecati blanditiis sed sequi nostrum quaerat voluptatibus, est libero culpa nemo! Quaerat, eaque.
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ratione, amet doloremque nulla iste atque reiciendis, autem, delectus fugiat sequi beatae praesentium molestias minima. Nostrum, consectetur, possimus provident facere, iusto officia tempore esse sapiente obcaecati quis dolorum fugiat blanditiis! Minus, sunt ex soluta eveniet odio sit nobis vero dolorem pariatur.
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente repellat placeat dignissimos provident commodi est quasi dolorem optio iusto officia earum facilis quae, magnam expedita mollitia vitae consectetur laborum quas in nam temporibus repudiandae fugit! A saepe obcaecati sapiente ullam ut labore odio. Voluptates quaerat, natus aspernatur vero debitis commodi perferendis laboriosam ut est sit nisi iste quisquam nostrum nam dolor exercitationem quos ipsum molestias eius veritatis fugit dolorem aliquid voluptate! Nam corporis fugiat nulla magnam, cupiditate maxime dolorem facilis quaerat laboriosam aspernatur illum in possimus doloribus voluptas porro voluptatem soluta, adipisci inventore, et commodi est odit nisi delectus? Rerum?
</p>
</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but using your solution we have  2 scroll bars... 1 for div, another for the page and I would like to avoid it. Just keep 1 scroll bar for the browser, not for div.